# Custom Elementor query to show a particular post linked to the current query

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I don’t know if anyone can help or I’m just being simple. I’m creating a template in Elementor to roll out across custom posts. The template itself is for a team but I need the info on the page to be dynamic based on whatever team is queried.

So for example there is a loop grid of coaches info which should be dynamically populated with the coaches relevant to that team.

I’m struggling to understand the logic to set this. Each team is a custom post and has coach data stored as a field with ACF. From what I can work out I need to set the query to be the current query so it populates the correct team but I also need it to show specifically the coaches and nothing else

I’ve tried to look up custom queries but as a non developer in stuggking to get my head around it